# Remove characters in textarea at the time of pasting text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Whenever i paste text in textarea , it should strip the character like <,>,@ etc. i try 
in JQuery

```
$('input').on('paste', function () { var element = this; setTimeout(function () { var text = $(element).val(); // do something with text }, 100); });
```

```js
$('input').on('paste', function () { 
    var element = this; 
    setTimeout(function () {
    var text = $(element).val(); 
    text.replace('<', '') );                                           
    }, 100); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="test" name="test" style="height:300px; width:400px"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `input` [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) which matches only elements with tagname as `input` like `<input type="..." />`, instead of `textarea` so

```js
$('textarea').on('paste', function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $el.val(function(i, val) {
      return val.replace(/[<>@]/g, '')
    })
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="test" name="test" style="height:300px; width:400px"></textarea>
```

Comment: May i know . why you use 'i' in this function
$el.val(function(i, val) {});

Comment: @BhaskarChalla that is the given format for the `.val()` callback function, `i` is the index of the current element